# how to check responce status use android.Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have following code

```
           JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (status == 202) {
                            // try again} else {
                               // do something                    
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.w("Request", "That didn't work!");
            }
        });

        queue.add(req);
```

but i don't know how i can get **status** code in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need override this method

```
@Override
protected  Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
  response.statusCode
}
```

regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the following code:

```
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                // do something...
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // do something...
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                int statusCode = response.statusCode;
                if (statusCode == 202) {
                    // do something...
                } else {
                    // do something...
                }
                ...                
            }
        };
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have not tried this resend yet, however you can try using `queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);` inside, or take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086386/how-to-resend-request-with-android-volley-when-not-authorized) for reference